# IE automation through excel vba looses focus with new url

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

```html
<DIV id=FAV class=parent noWrap><A onclick='window.event.cancelBubble=true; FolderExpand("FAV")' name=FAV><IMG onclick='window.event.cancelBubble=true; FolderExpand("FAV")' name=FAVTree src="images/Tplus_Top.gif" width=19 align=absMiddle height=20 TopTreeItem="true"><IMG onclick=folderClick() class=icon border=0 name=FAVFolder src="images/foldericon.gif" width=19 align=absMiddle height=20><SPAN onclick=looseFocus()>Favorites</SPAN></A></DIV>
```

Im trying to write a vb script to open a window>navigate to a site> log in> open a path in that site> search an order> and cancel the order. So far i have been able to open the site and log in, but at that point the URL changes and the error im getting seems to me like the script has lost focus on the IE window. i have the line "Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)" to set focus to the first URL (i believe) . but once i log in the URL gains "main.asp" at the end. I can provide the code but i believe the site is not supposed to be shared with non employees so ill have to remit that line. sorry for the lack of information. any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
    Const cUsername = "NSH******" 'Enter your user name here
    Const cPassword = "PASS*****" 'Enter your Password here
    Const cHM = "*********"       'Enter your HM here

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocumentCompatibleInfo
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement

    Dim favorites As HTMLDListElement
    Dim pktctrlsheet As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim pktctrlbox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim list As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim radio As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim actions As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://gws*********"


    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document
    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)
    Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("userID")
    UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername
    Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("userPassword")
    PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword
    Set SignInButton = LoginForm.elements("Login")
    SignInButton.Click

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set favorites = LoginForm.elements("FAV")
    favorites.Click

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The favorites variable is not set according to the error code. in the site its a drop down similar to an outlook inbox arrow. the other error code was something along the lines of "the sites allocation was revoked"

Comment: what is the html tagname of that dropdown element?

Comment: I dont know why the code is split up at the Loop Until ie.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE lines

Comment: I think that this line is probably wrong "Set favorites = LoginForm.elements("FAV") favorites.Click", .Click is an event that you cannot assign to variable. Also, after you clicked the SignInButton I assumed that the new page will load and you should set your doc variable again to ie.Document. Selecting value from a dropdown element depends on the element tagname, most of the time <select> is the element tagname for dropdown

Comment: Ok I found the correct tag name. I apologize this is the first time iam working with IE automation and the syntax is new to me. instead of .click what should I use? also what would the code look like whe I set the doc viariable? I currently have Set doc = ie.Document.forms(0)  Set favorites = LoginForm.elements("favorites"). this gives me "permission denied" when setting the favorites variable

Comment: Try to continue to search the elements on the page using ie.Document. It refers to that page which you had navigated before. If page get refreshed and new page got load than try to wait for that time and again try to assign the doc object and than after try to find the HTML elements on the page.

Comment: Please share the relevant html using snippet tool via [edit]. Also, see @Deepak-MSFT comment above.

Comment: would Dim favorites As HTMLDListElement be the correct way do classify an expanding option?

Comment: I have added the HTML for this section at the top

Comment: If you just declare all the object variables with object data type than also it would be fine. no need to create specific type of object for your HTML elements.